# Master Sheet pulling the same Cell of multiple tabs, using time to determine which cells are being pulled?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to pull info from the same cells of many tabs, and list them in a column depending on the day/time - ideally also using VLookup(?) rather than a straight query (to lessen the likelihood of the list ending up not matching the rest of the row). I have been able to accomplish this using IFs / strung together IF formulas, but that requires entering a formula into every cell of the column. I am hoping to lessen the number of formulas in this sheet (sometimes I get the never-ending loading of doom), and hope to be able to create the list with one header formula that auto-populates the whole column.

I've been trying to mess around with 3d references/DDDREF, VLookup, IFs/IF, Query, etc and haven't been able to find the correct order of things to make it happen. When I use the DDDREF by itself in a row, it works just fine, but when I try to use it within a string that looks at the day/time to decide which formula to populate, it only fills 1 cell instead of the full column and/or it says I can't reference now().

The sheet has many tabs, and the tabs change pretty frequently (added and removed), so it can't be something that requires listing out every tab. Here's what's being used in the column, currently (column S)

```
=T(N("TODAYS ARMING 1 TIME - .375 = 9am"))

&ifs(
$Z$1<1.374+N("  Sunday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D79"}),""),

$Z$1<2.374+N("   Monday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D67"}),""),

$Z$1<3.374+N("  Tuesday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D69"}),""),

$Z$1<4.374+N("Wednesday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D71"}),""),

$Z$1<5.374+N(" Thursday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D73"}),""),

$Z$1<6.374+N("   Friday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D75"}),""),

$Z$1<7.374+N(" Saturday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D77"}),""),

$Z$1>=7.374+N("  Sunday"),
IF($A3<>"",IMPORTRANGE($T$1,{$A3 &"!D79"}),""))
```

It breaks down to:
Column A has site names, which are also the tab names. It looks at Z1 to determine what day/time it is, and uses that to determine which cell to pull from each tab.

[Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E4cPIqLckUU9y1Zssh7L3AxxOYTsOhrJtHC-XkFfR3Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you!

Comment: in which cell/column/sheet you need that formula?

Comment: Would you be willing to accept a script version for this? If so, would you mind providing more information about the task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @player0 - this is one example from column S, but it's something I'd be re-creating for a number of different columns

Comment: @ale13 not against script (I currently have one that sorts tabs and creates a hyperlinked list of all tabs). Every tab has a lot of info that is used as criteria in other areas. I'm looking to lessen the number of duplicated formulas per row, into 1 that recreates the formula per row is a header auto-populating the full column.

Comment: So you would like to find a formula for each row of each tab? @MarcGolas

Comment: No, I'm looking for formulas to fill down columns S-AB (red areas) of 1st Tab (cover sheet). Every cell in those columns has a formula that works great, but I'm looking to condense it down to 1 header formula or a script (to lessen the number of formulas). You can ignore the row formulas present in the cover sheet (like B4:R), those are coming out as errors because I removed sensitive info it was originally pulling. AE2 is an example of what I'm looking for, but it's been tricky coordinating IFS, and pulling hyperlinks that are relevant to row.